# Spring boot not serving static files from inside jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring boot is not serving static files placed inside a jar.

I've had a backend app which I decided to add frontend to. Setup tasks to copy static frontend files to `src/main/resources/static`. Went through a bunch of answers here on SO, all of them advise the static content (index.html, .js and .css files) should reside under `src/main/resources/static` or `src/main/resources/public`, which i both tried. I open the built .jar and the static files are there, but starting application using `java -jar myApp.jar` and opening `localhost:8080` gives me default whitelabel error page. My application works, since i can access the api i have running on it.
Application doesn't have `@EnableWebMvc` or any other custom configuration.

If i manually copy/paste same static resources to project's `src/main/resources/static` and ran the application using @SpringBootApplication class in IDE - the resources are loaded without problem and index.html opens upon visiting `localhost:8080`, so it's only a problem when files are in .jar.
Should the static files be somewhere different when they're in runnable spring boot .jar file?
Spring boot version 2.1.1

Comment: have you tried to access them via full path (e.g. localhost:8080/index.html) when they are in a runnable jar?

Comment: Yes, trying to access directly via localhost:8080/index.html gives same error - not found.

Comment: How does your .jar file structure and inside it look like?

Comment: How does your POM/Gradle file look like? Seems like a project build issue..

Comment: To serve webpages(either static or dynamic) you need a framework like servlet/jsp or springboot. you are running it as standlone jar  (java -jar myApp.jar) doesn't tell anything to the server.

Comment: @SasiKathimanda that's incorrect. Spring-Boot is perfectly capable of serving static resources when they are configured correctly.

Comment: sure @LaksithaRanasingha , but without using `@SpringBootApplication` or other appropriate annotations will not make it a spring boot app?

Comment: @SasiKathimanda the OP said `ran the application using @SpringBootApplication class in IDE`.

Comment: It may help if OP shares the configuration files along with the project structure

Answer (score 3):

I am facing the same problem.

In case it is helpfull, I can manage to serve the static files properly by adding the following configuration  :

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class StaticFilesConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

... but it overrides the "implicit" auto configuration from spring boot and the rest of my filters etc. doesn't work anymore... => this is because `@EnableWebMvc` deactivates spring's default configuration.

**[EDIT]** In the end, I happened to understand that the jar containing the static files was not included in the built bootJar. You may want to check that.
HTH!

Comment: This configuration is not really required when you are serving static pages from the pre defines locations

Comment: Indeed @Prashant -unless you really was to serve it under /static/* URLs. BTW I found out that comment from Abhijit Sarkar in thread [/questions/24661289/spring-boot-not-serving-static-content] was really usefull. My problem was actually somewhere else - the jar containing static files was resolved by the IDE but not included in the product build... my bad! :) HTH anyway!

Comment: @Highbrainer Yes.. hit the same problem here. After tiresome inspection, found out it will not serve static content that has size 0 byte.

Comment: @below-1 I am having the exact same problem. Did somebody manage to tell Spring to also server zero-byte / empty files?